# double precision functions within the compute shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, compute-shader

I want to use some built-in functions like acos() for the type *double*. But it seems that some just exist for the usage with *float*.

In the [OpenGL Reference Card 4.3](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengl43-quick-reference-card.pdf), acos() is declared to be just usable with *floats* and [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/544159/request-for-extension-more-double-precision-functions-in-glsl/) someone asked for an extension to use more double precision functions with GLSL.

Is there another possibility to gain access to some double precision functions within a compute shader?

Comment: The kicker is whether a function has a `genDType` overload. The original double-precision FP extension ([`GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/gpu_shader_fp64.txt)) did not define them for the trig functions, and it seems no progress has been made to that end in the past 5 years :-\

Comment: Yep, no `genDType` overloads for any of the trig functions in the 4.3 spec.